# Alternatives to lanmessage

Tags: macos, instant-messaging, bonjour

I'm using lanmessage on OSX to send messages on a local network.

http://www.beckmanjm.com/freeware.html

I don't want to have to use a public service as such.  LanMessage works, but it's not fantastically useable.  I was wondering if anybody knew of an alternative that's a bit better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Growl's](http://growl.info/) remote capabilities to send notifications to other machines. `growlnotify` supports this from the command line.
[image]

---

You can also set up a local [Jabber](http://www.jabber.org/) server. This is an open messaging service similar to MSN or AIM, but you require no third party servers or internet connection for this. You can use e.g. [Adium](http://adium.im/) for the clients. This might be a bit much for your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Ip Messenger.](http://ipmsg.org/index.html.en) 
( We used this a lot in our University hostels and you dont need to setup a server for it)

>   Features of Ip Messenger :-
> 1. Multi Platform ( Windows, MacOS X and Unix ).
> 2. Open source and Free download.
> 3. Allows File and Folder transfer along the network.
> 4. Supports Broadcast Messages to a range of IP address.
> 5. You can lock your message with a password when its sent to other user.
> 6. You can even set your status.
> 7. Supports NIC extension in the latest version.
> 8. Messages can be logged in case you accidentally close the message box.
> 9. Shows the Ip address, login user, machine name of the other users.